# acts_as_commentable without title field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, acts-as-commentable

I'm very much interested in the acts_as_commentable gem, but by looking at it I see that it has a column in the database for comment titles. I would not need a title, but I do want to save time by using the gem.

Are there any existing forks that have removed the title field, or should I just skip on and simple ignore the title field when creating & presenting comments? I'm pretty sure I can fork the gem and remove any validations/traces of that column but I'd prefer an existing solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no validations in place so removing the title field from the database entirely is no problem. Just remove it from the migration.